# Firebase authentication stream not working

Tags: flutter, dart

In this Project I'm using firebase authentication and for changing homepage of the `MaterialApp` a `StreamBuilder` is implemented at `MaterialApp`'s home section but its not working as expected.

home of the MaterialApp,

```
  home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Constants.firebaseUser = snapshot.data!;

                return FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseServices.getUserType(snapshot.data!.uid),
                    builder: (context, snap) {
                      if (snap.data == UserType.doctor) {
                        return const DoctorHomePage();
                      } else if (snap.data == UserType.patient) {
                        return const UserHomePage();
                      } else if (snap.data == UserType.admin) {
                        return const AdminHome();
                      } else {
                        return const LoadingSplash();
                      }
                    });
              } else {
                return const LoginPage();
              }
            }));
```

It should change the homepage from login to any of those pages at the time of successful login.
But it only navigating to those home page only after restart.
PS. here I'm using another future function to find the category in which the user falls in.

Comment: This code looks fine. Can you share more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use getxcontroller

```
 class AuthController extends GetxController {


 late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


@override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(_user, initialScreen);
  }

      initialScreen(User? user) {
        if (user == null) {
            //navigate to login screen
        } else {
            //navigate to home screen
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use getx